# Ollydbg - change string's first letter

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I've written a small .exe program in C++.

```
int main()
{                         

    string myString = "Hello";
    printf("%s", myString);    
    return 0;
}
```

I need to use ollydbg in order to replace the first letter in the string and then print it.
Alternatively, I can print a different string entirely.
I've loaded the .exe file to ollydbg, found the execution are where printf is called, but cannot find the JMP command that leads to it.

How can overcome this?
I've Googled for tutorials but did not find anything similar to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find that, even with Olly, this is difficult to achieve.  The string that you have there should be in the read-only text segment as a literal string.  You may find that you would need to modify it in the binary image on the disk instead.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, It was suggested to me to use boolean algebra (for example AND with 0xFFFF FFDF) or ADD/SUB operations.
Another option for me is to change it from 'H' to 'h'.

What about replacing the string with a different one?
So before printf is called, I pass a different string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the string with
Context menu->Search for->All referenced text strings

In the same window with the references, there are the addresses which you can edit using CTRL+E (Binary edit)

Comment: CTRL-E does nothing

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change it permanently do this:

- press `alt + e`
- find your exe file. select it `right click` and select `View executable file`.
- press `ctrl+B` and search for hello. and change the h.
- `right click` and select `Save file...`.

Comment: How can I change it? Looks like it is not possible

Comment: Figured it out... mark text -> right click -> binary -> edit